Bidirectional communication using custom cluster ESP32H2 (ESP32 Zigbee SDK )
I used a code that sends string between to nodes (Coordinator/End device). the coordinator can send write command to the end device but the end device can not although each node has two clusters (client & server).
I am using arduino IDE and the code is taken from esp IDF example with some modifications.
The main issue is that the Coordinator can not listen to the message from the EndDevice.
Here is the codes: --> Coordinator
`
static void esp_zb_task(void *pvParameters) {
  /* initialize Zigbee stack */
  esp_zb_cfg_t zb_nwk_cfg = ESP_ZB_ZC_CONFIG();
  esp_zb_init(&zb_nwk_cfg);
  
  // 
  esp_zb_ep_list_t *ep_list = esp_zb_ep_list_create();
  esp_zb_cluster_list_t *cluster_list = esp_zb_zcl_cluster_list_create();
  
  // cluster to turn ON/OFF
  esp_zb_on_off_cluster_cfg_t on_off_cfg;
  on_off_cfg.on_off = ESP_ZB_ZCL_ON_OFF_ON_OFF_DEFAULT_VALUE;
  esp_zb_attribute_list_t *esp_zb_on_off_cluster = esp_zb_on_off_cluster_create(&on_off_cfg);
  esp_zb_cluster_list_add_on_off_cluster(cluster_list, esp_zb_on_off_cluster, ESP_ZB_ZCL_CLUSTER_CLIENT_ROLE);
  
  // add custom attribute
  esp_zb_attribute_list_t *custom_attr = esp_zb_zcl_attr_list_create(CUSTOM_CLUSTER_ID);
  uint8_t custom_string[CUSTOM_STRING_MAX_SIZE] = "_hello_world";
  custom_string[0] = CUSTOM_STRING_MAX_SIZE - 1;

  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_zb_custom_cluster_add_custom_attr(custom_attr, 0x02, ESP_ZB_ZCL_ATTR_TYPE_CHAR_STRING, ESP_ZB_ZCL_ATTR_ACCESS_READ_WRITE, custom_string));
  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_zb_cluster_list_add_custom_cluster(cluster_list, custom_attr, ESP_ZB_ZCL_CLUSTER_CLIENT_ROLE));

  // ####################### add Rx cluster to Rx custom attribute ######################################
  esp_zb_attribute_list_t *custom_attr1 = esp_zb_zcl_attr_list_create(CUSTOM_CLUSTER_ID1);

  esp_zb_custom_cluster_add_custom_attr(custom_attr1, 0x01, ESP_ZB_ZCL_ATTR_TYPE_CHAR_STRING, ESP_ZB_ZCL_ATTR_ACCESS_READ_WRITE, custom_string);
  esp_zb_cluster_list_add_custom_cluster(cluster_list, custom_attr1, ESP_ZB_ZCL_CLUSTER_SERVER_ROLE);

  // device discription struc
  esp_zb_endpoint_config_t endpoint_config = {
      .endpoint = HA_ONOFF_SWITCH_ENDPOINT,
      .app_profile_id = ESP_ZB_AF_HA_PROFILE_ID,
      .app_device_id = ESP_ZB_HA_CUSTOM_ATTR_DEVICE_ID,
      .app_device_version = 0,
  };

  esp_zb_ep_list_add_ep(ep_list, cluster_list, endpoint_config);
  esp_zb_device_register(ep_list);
  esp_zb_set_primary_network_channel_set(ESP_ZB_PRIMARY_CHANNEL_MASK);
  esp_zb_core_action_handler_register(zb_action_handler);
  //Erase NVRAM before creating connection to new Coordinator | keeps binding table 
  esp_zb_nvram_erase_at_start(true);  //Comment out this line to erase NVRAM data if you are conneting to new Coordinator
  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_zb_start(false));
  esp_zb_main_loop_iteration();
}

`
--> End device
`
`    static void esp_zb_task(void *pvParameters)
{
  /* initialize Zigbee stack */
  esp_zb_cfg_t zb_nwk_cfg = ESP_ZB_ZED_CONFIG();
  esp_zb_init(&zb_nwk_cfg);

  // 
  esp_zb_ep_list_t *ep_list = esp_zb_ep_list_create();
  esp_zb_cluster_list_t *cluster_list = esp_zb_zcl_cluster_list_create();

  // cluster to turn ON/OFF
  esp_zb_on_off_cluster_cfg_t on_off_cfg;
  on_off_cfg.on_off = ESP_ZB_ZCL_ON_OFF_ON_OFF_DEFAULT_VALUE;
  esp_zb_attribute_list_t *esp_zb_on_off_cluster = esp_zb_on_off_cluster_create(&on_off_cfg);// SERVER
  esp_zb_cluster_list_add_on_off_cluster(cluster_list, esp_zb_on_off_cluster, ESP_ZB_ZCL_CLUSTER_SERVER_ROLE);

  // add custom attribute
  esp_zb_attribute_list_t *custom_attr = esp_zb_zcl_attr_list_create(CUSTOM_CLUSTER_ID);
  uint8_t custom_string[CUSTOM_STRING_MAX_SIZE] = "_ESPRESSIF";
  custom_string[0] = CUSTOM_STRING_MAX_SIZE - 1;

  //
  esp_zb_custom_cluster_add_custom_attr(custom_attr, 0x02, ESP_ZB_ZCL_ATTR_TYPE_CHAR_STRING, ESP_ZB_ZCL_ATTR_ACCESS_READ_WRITE, custom_string);
  esp_zb_cluster_list_add_custom_cluster(cluster_list, custom_attr, ESP_ZB_ZCL_CLUSTER_SERVER_ROLE);

  // ####################### add Tx cluster to Rx custom attribute ######################################
  // cluster to turn ON/OFF  
  esp_zb_attribute_list_t *custom_attr1 = esp_zb_zcl_attr_list_create(CUSTOM_CLUSTER_ID1);

  //
  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_zb_custom_cluster_add_custom_attr(custom_attr1, 0x02, ESP_ZB_ZCL_ATTR_TYPE_CHAR_STRING, ESP_ZB_ZCL_ATTR_ACCESS_READ_WRITE, custom_string));
  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_zb_cluster_list_add_custom_cluster(cluster_list, custom_attr1, ESP_ZB_ZCL_CLUSTER_CLIENT_ROLE));

  // device discription struc
  esp_zb_endpoint_config_t endpoint_config = {
    .endpoint = HA_ESP_LIGHT_ENDPOINT,
    .app_profile_id = ESP_ZB_AF_HA_PROFILE_ID,
    .app_device_id = ESP_ZB_HA_CUSTOM_ATTR_DEVICE_ID,
    .app_device_version = 0,
  };

  // device discription struc
  esp_zb_endpoint_config_t endpoint_config1 = {
    .endpoint = HA_ESP_LIGHT_ENDPOINT1,
    .app_profile_id = ESP_ZB_AF_HA_PROFILE_ID,
    .app_device_id = ESP_ZB_HA_CUSTOM_ATTR_DEVICE_ID,
    .app_device_version = 0,
  };
  esp_zb_ep_list_add_ep(ep_list, cluster_list, endpoint_config1);

  // 
  esp_zb_ep_list_add_ep(ep_list, cluster_list, endpoint_config);
  esp_zb_device_register(ep_list);

  esp_zb_zcl_custom_cluster_handlers_t obj = {.cluster_id = CUSTOM_CLUSTER_ID,
                                              .cluster_role = ESP_ZB_ZCL_CLUSTER_SERVER_ROLE,
                                              .check_value_cb = esp_zb_zcl_cluster_check_value_handler,
                                              .write_attr_cb = esp_zb_zcl_cluster_write_attr_handler};

  esp_zb_zcl_custom_cluster_handlers_update(obj);
  //********************************** Added by me
  //Erase NVRAM before creating connection to new Coordinator | keeps binding table 
  esp_zb_nvram_erase_at_start(true);  //Comment out this line to erase NVRAM data if you are conneting to new Coordinator
  //********************************************
  esp_zb_core_action_handler_register(zb_action_handler);
  esp_zb_set_primary_network_channel_set(ESP_ZB_PRIMARY_CHANNEL_MASK);
  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_zb_start(false));
  esp_zb_main_loop_iteration();
}

``
1- I added the second cluster to give the required functionality.
2- I added action handlers for the write command however no response.
